On JSP page unable to get attribute from a Servlet with and without getSession()
I have a web app that must get the city's name by an API request, it should give the foirecast for that city. But in the JSP file I am not able to get a variable with getAttribute() from the setAttribute() in the servlet. Don't know why.
Servlet:
package package1;

//Librerie da Importare
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


// Definisce la servlet con nome "MyServlet" e specifica il l'indirizzo dell'URL a cui andare
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    //Variabile identificatore della versione attuale per la serializzazione
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    //Costruttore che chiama il costruttore della superclasse
    public MyServlet()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    //Metodo che processa ogni richiesta fatta, dicendo che la risposta deve essere di tipo HTML
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    }
    
    //Metodo per le richieste HTTP Get
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    //Metodo per le richieste HTTP Post
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //Chiave Personale dell’API OpenWeatherMap
        String chiaveAPI = "47da379d1f4d98cfb31a7fa10a00c010";
        
        //Stringa per la variabile della città da cercare
        String città = request.getParameter("città");
        
        //URL creato, da inviare per la API request
        String apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +città+ "&appid="+ chiaveAPI;
        
        try
        {
            //Integrazione con l’API
            //Oggetto di tipo URL con l'URL dell'API.
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            
            //Apre una connessione HTTP all'URL
            HttpURLConnection connessione = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            
            //Setta il metodo della richiesta HTTP a Get
            connessione.setRequestMethod("GET");

            
            //Legge i dati dalla rete;
            //Prende il flusso di input dalla connessione aperta
            InputStream inpStream = connessione.getInputStream();
            
            //InputStreamReader per leggere dal flusso di input
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inpStream);

            
            //Salva i dati presi nella stringa definita, con uno StringBuilder
            StringBuilder risposta = new StringBuilder();

            //Crea un’oggetto scanner per prendere in input dal reader
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                risposta.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();


            //La risposta prodotta dalla API produce un file in formato JSON
            //Deserializzazione del file JSON in un oggetto
            //Crea un oggetto gson
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            
            //Converte la stringa JSON in un oggetto JsonObject
            JsonObject oggettoJSON = gson.fromJson(risposta.toString(), JsonObject.class);
            
            //Stampa l'oggetto
            System.out.println(oggettoJSON);

            
            //Parte per estrarre i dati dal JSON e salvarli
            //Temperatura
            double temperaturaKelvin = oggettoJSON.getAsJsonObject("main").get("temp").getAsDouble();
            int temperatura = (int)(temperaturaKelvin - 273.15);
             
            
            //Umidità
            int umidità = oggettoJSON.getAsJsonObject("main").get("humidity").getAsInt();
        
            
            //Velocità del Vento
            double velocitàVento = oggettoJSON.getAsJsonObject("wind").get("speed").getAsDouble();
                 
            
            //Visibiltà
            int visibilitàMetri = oggettoJSON.get("visibility").getAsInt();
            int visibilità = visibilitàMetri / 1000;
               
            
            //Condizioni Meteo Generali
            String condizioni = oggettoJSON.getAsJsonArray("weather").get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("main").getAsString();
                
            
            //Copertura Nuvole
            int nuvole = oggettoJSON.getAsJsonObject("clouds").get("all").getAsInt();
                 
            
            //Tempo e Data Attuali al momento della richiesta
            //Estrae il formato dell'ora della data dalla risposta JSON.
            long x = oggettoJSON.get("dt").getAsLong() * 1000;
            
            //Crea un SimpleDateFormat per formattare la data
            SimpleDateFormat y = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
            
            //Converte il timestamp in una stringa di data formattata
            String data = y.format(new Date(x));

            
            //Formato dell’ora
            //Crea un SimpleDateFormat per formattare l'ora
            SimpleDateFormat z = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            
            //Ottiene l'ora formattata
            String ora = z.format(new Date());


            //Setta i dati presi dal JSON per mandarli alla pagina JSP
            request.setAttribute("date", data);
            request.setAttribute("city", città);
            request.setAttribute("visibility",visibilità);
            request.setAttribute("temperature", temperatura);
            request.setAttribute("weatherCondition", condizioni); 
            request.setAttribute("humidity", umidità);    
            request.setAttribute("windSpeed", velocitàVento);
            request.setAttribute("cloudCover", nuvole);
            request.setAttribute("currentTime", ora);
            request.setAttribute("weatherData", risposta.toString());
            
            request.setAttribute("pisello", 1);
            
            
            //Chiusura della connessione HTTP
            connessione.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("pisello", "funzionaOK");
        
        //Manda la richiesta al file JSP per elaborare i dati da mostrare
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
    }
}


JSP:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Web App Meteo - Dettagli</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsp-style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>Dettagli Meteo</h1>

                <div class="weather-image-container">
                    <img id="weather-icon" src="immagine/img1.png" alt="Weather Image">
                        <div class="temp-city">
                            <h2>
                                <i class="fas fa-city"></i> ${city}
                            </h2>
                            <h2>
                                <i class="fas fa-thermometer-half"></i> ${temperature}&deg;C
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="weather-info">
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Data: ${date}
                    </p>
                    
                    
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Prova: ${pisello}
                        <%=request.getSession().getAttribute("pisello")%>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> Ora Attuale: ${currentTime}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-sun"></i> Condizioni: ${weatherCondition}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Visibilità: ${visibility}km
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-wind"></i> Velocita del Vento: ${windSpeed}km/hr
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i> Copertura delle Nuvole: ${cloudCover}%
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Esegui una nuova ricerca rapida da qui</h2>
                    <form id="formMeteo" action="MyServlet" method="post">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Es. Roma, New York, Londra">
                        <button type="submit">Cerca</button>
                        <p id="messaggioErrore" style="color: red; padding: 6px 6px; display: none;">Inserisci il nome di una città</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer-container">
            <p>Realizzato dal Gruppo di Lavoro: D.Salvatore, D.Tirro, M.Picciuto, D. Tamilia - 5BI</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>

HTML:
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Web App Meteo - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Web App Meteo</h1>
            
            <form id="formMeteo" action="MyServlet" method="post">
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Inserisci il nome della città">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Cerca
                    </button>
                    <p id="messaggioErrore" style="color: red; padding: 6px 6px; display: none;">Please enter the name of the place.</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer-container">
            <p>Realizzato dal Gruppo di Lavoro: D.Salvatore, D.Tirro, M.Picciuto, D. Tamilia - 5BI</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</html>

JS:
document.getElementById('formMeteo').addEventListener('submit', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); //Per prevenire l'invio del form nello stato di default/predefinito
    
    var cittàInput = document.getElementById('city');
    var messaggioErrore = document.getElementById('messaggioErrore');
    
    if (cittàInput.value.trim() === '')
    {
        messaggioErrore.style.display = 'block'; //Mostra messaggio di errore
    }
    else
    {
        messaggioErrore.style.display = 'none'; //Nascondi il messaggio
        this.submit(); //invia il form
    }
});

The JSP should get the value from the Servlet and show the value of the variable in a HTML page without problem, but my variable is null.

Looks to me that you're looking for the parameter by its Italian name but it has an English name in the client form

Which variable do you mean?

String città = request.getParameter("città"); Not only are you using the wrong name, but you're even using a diacritic

With getSession().getAttribute() you can get only a session scope attribute. But you put an attribute to the request scope.
request.setAttribute("city", città);

If you want to get an attribute from a session scope then you should use
request.getSession().setAttribute("city", città);

The request attributes are available in JSP if you use dispatcher to forward the request. If you redirect to another URL then you should use session scope attributes.
Also, you didn't submit the value of the attribute or getting it from the wrong key. As mentioned by @g00se:
String città = request.getParameter("città");

is always null, because you submit a parameter name city.
